# Unable to get java project to recognize Open CV library

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I have code that is supposed to create a video capture from my web cam and let me know that it has been found using OpenCV, but I can't even get project to recognize it as a library. I have added OpenCv to the project libraries and everything. I am unsure if I am using the right name for the library though. I just used the same name that I gave it when I created the user library.

Here is my code

```
package com.example.frametest;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

public class FrameTest {

public static void main (String[] args){
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(0);

    if(!cap.isOpened()){
        System.out.println("Did not connect to camera");

    }else System.out.println("found webcam:" + cap.toString());
    //Mat frame = new Mat();
    //cap.retrieve(frame);

}

}
```

And here is the message from the error box

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.example.frametest.FrameTest.main(FrameTest.java:9)
```

Any suggestions about what I did wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to download the OpenCv.exe file instead of just the .zip file. Then I had to set up the native library locations to the java folders within its build folder. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a native .dll/.so library in the Java system property java.library.path.  Change your launcher to -Djava.library.path=the_right_folder as one of the VM arguments.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add it the library to the project?

If you have done it via eclipse correcting ([like this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F)) then you shouldn't need to have the line

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
```

as it is imported with your import statements at the top of your class.

Alternatively you might want to try using

```
System.loadLibrary("org.opencv");
```